# limiting master data frame to a certain point

Tags: r

I'm trying to input id and get back a master dataframe up to the id file number I try this

```
pollutant<-function(id,pollutant){
for (i in 1:id) {
 filenames=list.files(pattern="csv")
df.list = lapply(filenames, function(i) na.omit(read.csv(i)))
master.df = do.call(rbind, df.list)}
master.df}
```

but it keeps giving me all the files in a data frame
help anyone?

Comment: Where are you using `i` in your `for` loop?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend just using `data.table`.

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(lapply(list.files(pattern = "csv"), fread))
```

I think you can wrap `rbindlist` with `na.omit` to get the complete cases. Also it's not clear what you're using `id` for?

Answer (score 1):

i think you were after this (untested)

```
pollutant <- function(id){

  filenames=list.files(pattern="csv")
  df.list = lapply(filenames[1:id], function(f) na.omit(read.csv(f)))
  do.call(rbind, df.list)

}
```